# How to get layer description using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

Assuming we have a ILayer object, I'm looking for how to get the layer description.

I mean the description text of the layer properties:

[image]

I didn't find it into the ArcObjects documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access this through [ILayerGeneralProperties](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/ILayerGeneralProperties.htm) "LayerDescription" property:

```
Dim pLayerFile As ILayerFile
Set pLayerFile = New LayerFile

pLayerFile.Open ("C:\Tmp\Robert.lyr")

Dim pLayer As ILayer
Set pLayer = pLayerFile.Layer

Dim pLayerGenProp As ILayerGeneralProperties
Set pLayerGenProp = pLayer

MsgBox pLayerGenProp.LayerDescription
```

Code courtesy of [Chirag Danech](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=290101)

---

Or, if you have a MapServerLayer, Use [IMapLayerInfo](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMapLayerInfo_Interface/0012000008v2000000/)'s "Description" property:

[image]